# Javascript, base 10 to base 8

Tags: javascript

How do I convert base 10 to base 8 in javascript? I tried with `parseInt(text, 8)` but the problem with that, is when I write 8 or 9 it says `NaN` I know 8 and 9 don't exists in base 8. But it should say 10 and 11 instead of `NaN`

EDIT: Here is the whole function

```
            function toBaseEight(){
                var text = document.getElementById('base10').value;
                var base8 = parseInt(text, 8);
                document.getElementById('base8').innerHTML = base8;
            }
```

Comment: Check if this helps:- http://david.tribble.com/src/javascript/jsconvert.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following code

```
text.toString(8);
```

or try

```
parseInt(text).toString(8)
```

Comment: That just return the number without converting it.

Comment: try this 

`parseInt(text).toString(8)`

Comment: change your function 

`function toBaseEight(){
                var text = document.getElementById('base10').value;
                var base8 = (parseInt(text).toString(8));
    alert("d");
                document.getElementById('base8').innerHTML = base8;
            }`

Answer (score 9):

You can pass a radix to [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString):

```
> (9).toString(8)
11
```

In your specific case, you can write:

```
document.getElementById("base8").innerHTML
    = parseInt(document.getElementById("base10").value, 10).toString(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try `(number).toString(8)`. Or you could use `parseInt ("number", 8)`. You must have forgotten the quotes.

Comment: I tested with different versions of toString. but it still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that the number on the left hand side of the bracket is to the base of the radix in the right hand side so it's returning the decimal equivalent.

`parseInt(10, 8)` is asking  1×8^1 + 0×8^0 = 8

`parseInt(12, 8)` is asking  1×8^1 + 2×8^0 = 8 + 2 = 10

`parseInt(7, 8)` is asking 7×8^0 = 7

Therefore it is quite difficult to have 9 come out as 11 as 13 in octal is 11...

You can do as the answers above have mentioned to convert the decimal number to octal rather then vice-versa which is what parseInt was doing: `(x).toString(y)`